# Oracle Query is returning value when setting value to it, but not returning value when passing date value

Tags: oracle

My below query is not returning any values when i pass the START_DATE and END_DATE as parameter to my oracle procedure. But when i set actual date in the query i am getting results. Kindly help me what is the mistake i have done here. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT INCIDENT_ID 
FROM INC_SM1 I 
WHERE 
    I.CLOSE_TIME >= TO_DATE(START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND I.CLOSE_TIME < TO_DATE(END_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

The below query is returning values, when I run my procedure

```
SELECT INCIDENT_ID 
FROM INC_SM1 I 
WHERE 
    I.CLOSE_TIME >= TO_DATE('01-JUL-2013 00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') 
AND I.CLOSE_TIME < TO_DATE('01-AUG-2013 00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
```

Note: My input to procedure is `TO_DATE('01-JUL-2013 00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')`

Comment: Can you paste the complete (relevant parts) of the procedure? Looks like you are doing to_date twice? Once inside teh procedure and once in the argument?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already forcing the date format, you can use the following query instead:

```
SELECT INCIDENT_ID 
FROM INC_SM1 I 
WHERE 
    I.CLOSE_TIME >= START_DATE
AND I.CLOSE_TIME < END_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes i did the to_date twice and hence i faced the issue. As per the above suggestion i changed my query and it is working fine.. Thanks.